# How to redirect correctly a root domain to a subdomain in a subfolder?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

The next `.htaccess` code redirects `example.com` (from */public_html* root folder) to the `subdomain1.example.com` (to */public_html/subdomain1* subdolder) and an old page *register* to a new one at `subdomain1.example.com/enroll`. So far so good! But, I have also a subdomain `subdomain2.example.com` (in the */public_html/subdomain2* subfolder) that instead of his normal URL is redirected to the `subdomain1.example.com/subfolder2`, that not exists. Why this happens and how to avoid this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain1.example com/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /register http://subdomain1.example com/enroll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the adopted answer, thanks to @anubhava:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !subdomain.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Sourse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323457/1354580